# How can function in interface call its own data?

Tags: typescript

I am implementing an interface which contains a function. However, I cannot let the function access the data in the interface via `this`. I guess this is because of interface.

```
export interface A {
   data: any;
   func(): void {
      this.data = xxx;  // this cannot compile
   }
}
```

So what is the workround?

Comment: An interface can contain a method _definition_, but (as it does not exist at runtime) not a method _implementation_.

Comment: What is the actual use case?  Interfaces don't exist at runtime and have no runtime behavior, so they can't have implementations inside them.  Maybe you want a class?  Maybe you want an interface and then implement it with an object? That is: [do either of these approaches meet your needs?](https://tsplay.dev/w86lEm)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The interface cannot contain an implementation, make sure to separate those:

```
interface A {
   data: any;
   func: () => void
}

const implementsA: A = {
  data: 5,
  func() {
    this.data = 6
  }
}

implementsA.func()

console.log(implementsA.data) // 6
```